# Testing Unirest with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, unirest

I want to test a method that sends a get request to a server using Unirest

I have used PowerMockito and Mockito to test some methods, but when I try to do it on the method below, I get null pointer exception.

This is the method I want to test:

```
public HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonRequest(String path) {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = Unirest
                    .get(path)
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            System.out.println("Server is unreachable at the moment. Please try again later");
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

And this is the test case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Unirest.class)

public class TestModel {

    @Mock
    private GetRequest getRequest;

    @Mock
    private HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse;

    @InjectMocks
    DatabaseModel databaseModel;

    @Test
    public void testController() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Unirest.class);
        JsonNode jsonNode = mock(JsonNode.class);
        when(Unirest.get("12345")).thenReturn(getRequest);
        when(getRequest.asJson()).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(httpResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);

        assertEquals(200, databaseModel.jsonRequest("12345").getStatus());
    }
```

So I expect to get 200 (Or any status\body I will decide on)
But for some reason I get java.lang.NullPointerException
which directs me to this line:

```
.asJson();
```

in the getRequest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you forgot to set-up the header:

```
    when(Unirest.get("12345")).thenReturn(getRequest);
    when(getRequest.header("accept", "application/json").thenReturn(getRequest)
    when(getRequest.asJson()).thenReturn(httpResponse);
    when(httpResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);
```